# Retaining access to table that will be dropped and recreated

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, permissions

I have a small GIS table that is is dropped and recreated from a third-party tool called MAPINFO.

Each time I drop and recreate that table I grant access to roles created. Is it possible to retain access even after drop and create?

I cannot run SQL through Mapinfo. It does not provide *truncate table* - it just drops the table and creates a new one.

Answer (score 0):

*<sub>Answer left in comments by [spaghettidba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3020/spaghettidba)</sub>*

Do you have control over the schema where the table gets created?

If so, you could grant privileges on the *schema*.

Another option is a DDL trigger to grant permissions on the table upon creation.